# Link the movement of a CollectionView to an image

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: Example]In a page I inserted a `ScrollView` in which I have an `Image` and a `CollectionView` inside.
I would like the image to be able to scroll together with the `CollectionView`, remaining at the top. I could put it in the `CollectionView.Header`, but I need to hide or show the image, so I put it outside the `CollectionView`. Do I have a way to 'anchor' the image to the `CollectionView`?

UPDATE:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout ShouldKineticScroll="True">
         <xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.TopView>
              <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="33"/>
                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <Image
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2"
                         Source="ExpanderPlus"
                         Margin="22"/>
                       <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Dimenticato niente?" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/
                </Grid>
             </xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.TopView>


             <xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.BottomView>
            <CollectionView
             x:Name="CollectionDiary"
              Grid.Row="1">
              //Other code
     </xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.BottomView>
    </xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: "scroll together" and "remain at the top"? Do you mean the image is quite large and needs to scroll to view or are you scrolling the CollectionView? Any design images for more detail?

Comment: I have updated my post with image

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the effect like `CoordinatorLayout`.

You could look at [CoordinatorLayout.XamarinForms](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/CoordinatorLayout.Forms)

**Update**：

```
<xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.TopView>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="33"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Image
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Grid.RowSpan="2"
                     Source="ExpanderPlus"
                     Margin="22"/>
                   <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Dimenticato niente?" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/
            </Grid>  
       
</xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.TopView>

<xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.BottomView>
     <StackLayout x:Name="_stackLayout" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Your data}">          
         <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                    //define your template
          </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
     </StackLayout>
      
 </xamarinForms:CoordinatorLayout.BottomView>
```

Comment: I looked but i can't figure out how to merge both the image and the collectionView. I updated my post with an image

Comment: You could the Image into `CoordinatorLayout.TopView` and add the collectionView to `CoordinatorLayout.BottomView`

Comment: I have updated the code, you can see it. But I can't connect the collectionView with the rest of things together. From what I understand CoordinatorLayout.TopView must necessarily zoom in and out of the TopView view and not just connect it together with the BottomView, or can't I?

Comment: @signalover Yes,it will zoom in and out of the topview,and i test it,it seems that you could not add the collectionview to BottomView directly,but you could try to use `BindableLayout` for a stack layout like the update above.

Comment: Why do you recommend a StackLayout? I need a collectionView

Comment: @signalover You use StackLayout with BindableLayout here has the same effect as collectionview,and it could achieve the effect you want.You could have a try.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use a stackLayout because I need a CollectionView with groups. so is there a way to use that control did you recommend me? Or another method for someone like me who needs a collectionView? thank you

Comment: I only find the way use stacklayout to instead of collectionview in this library,if you want the group,you also could define a template in the stacklayou.